# No scrollbar on my website elements in Chrome/Opera browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, blink

I have a problem with my website. It's based on PHPBB3 Forum and I need solution for this problem: People can't see scrollbars in all components on my website. The scrollbar itself exists but it's invisible, like his opacity is somehow set to 0. For instance, there is no visible scrollbars on shoutbox in this screenshot, but you can still scroll by grabbing this white space and dragging it up and down (like having an invisible scrollbar xd):

[image]

On Firefox everything is fine, but on Chrome and Opera(*Webkit* and *blink* engine) is not.

I don't know what possibly can make this, so I'm searching for some solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,
Areen.

Comment: Is there a specific code that we can look at?

Comment: In chrome the scrollbar is not visible until you use it

Comment: @Yotam, I'm sorry but there is no specific code :(

Comment: @aldanux, I think that "feature" is on every browser but nvm. xD 

The scroll exists by itselft, but u can't really see it. You can scroll by grabbing this white surface in shoutbox, but scroll simply doesn't appear, like I've said, opacity is set to 0 somehow. The same thing happends when you have to write a post. In edit section you can't see the scrollbar, but you can use it. Shoutbox is only an example of this situation. This problem concerns to whole content.

Comment: Maybe the url will be helpful? [link](http://www.generally.pl)

Comment: @Areen - I see the scrollbar in Chrome and FF...also you have an error: `Request URL:http://www.generally.pl/jquery.min.map
Status Code:404 Not Found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your body element's CSS, there is a webkit property;

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
```

It is right here in your stylesheet on line 36:

http://www.generally.pl/style.php?id=4&lang=en

```
body {
    /* Text-Sizing with ems: http://www.clagnut.com/blog/348/ */
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*font-size: 62.5%;          This sets the default font size to be equivalent to 10px */
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
}
```

Unchecking this property in Chrome's inspector (F12) makes your scrollbar show up.  My guess is that the original designer wanted to hide the scrollbar, so a very slight offset made it disappear.  just comment out or delete this section and you will be  fine.

Sorry I gave a quick answer earlier without actually trying it. I have deleted that post.  This answer WILL work for Chrome.  It should also work for Opera, though I don't have Opera installed on any of my computers.  According to this Sitepoint article from May of last year, Opera implemented webkit extensions (but it doesn't list webkit-transform specifically):

http://www.sitepoint.com/opera-css3-webkit-prefix/

Comment: @areen it would be cool if you could accept the answer.  There is a check box....

Answer (score 0):

Set the div's style property to `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: It's already done. Scroll exists in marked part of the screen. It's simply invisible.